# Using foreach for query PHP

Tags: php, html

How can i get posts from user i follow?I have got this code

```
<?php
    $query=$con->query("SELECT Following FROM followers WHERE Follower='$Name'");

    while ($row=$query->fetch_row()){
        $Follower=$row[0];
        $query2=$con->query("SELECT Image,`Text` FROM uploads WHERE Username='$Follower'");
    } 

    while ($row2=$query2->fetch_row()) {
        $Image=$row2[0];
        $Text=$row2[1];
        $Likes=$row2[2];
        $Comments=$row2[3];
        $Reposts=$row2[4];
?>
        <div class="PF">  
            <img src="../users/<?php echo $roww[0] ?>" class="FollowerPic">
            <span><?php echo $Follower?></span>
        </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

But it does not work it only gives me posts of the last user

Comment: Proper indentation helps see where error might be.

Comment: When you think you need to write nested queries, you probably _actually_ need to write a JOIN query.  Your is unstable (and potentially insecure); please research prepared statements and implement placeholders with bound variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this. put the second "while" into the first one.

```
<?php
            $query=$con->query("SELECT Following FROM followers WHERE Follower='$Name'");

                    while ($row=$query->fetch_row()){
                        $Follower=$row[0];
                        $query2=$con->query("SELECT Image,`Text` FROM uploads WHERE Username='$Follower'");


                       while ($row2=$query2->fetch_row()) {
                           $Image=$row2[0];
                           $Text=$row2[1];
                           $Likes=$row2[2];
                           $Comments=$row2[3];
                           $Reposts=$row2[4];


                           ?>
                           <div class="PF">
                               <img src="../users/<?php echo $roww[0] ?>" class="FollowerPic">
                               <span><?php echo $Follower?></span>
                           </div>

                           <?php
                       }
                    }
?>
```

But anyway better to use it in  1 query [(LEFT JOIN)](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

LEFT JOIN example;

```
<?php

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM followers AS f LEFT JOIN uploads AS u ON  f.Following = u.Username WHERE f.Follower='$Name' ORDER BY u.date LIMIT 0,250";
            $query=$con->query($sql);
            echo '<pre>';
            while ($row=$query->fetch_row()){
                print_r($row);
            }
            echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: But then how can i order all this posts by 'date'?

Comment: Your code get the follower with first follower and then gets all his posts.I tried code it only returns all posts of first user

Comment: Its hard to understand without see your database tables. But can you see second example that I added my post.

Comment: Second code is LEFT JOIN example, its doing same things that first code is doing. I'm trying to say, you don't need 2 while for do this. If you share your table fields, will be easy to help you.

Comment: So i should put it instead of two whiles?

Comment: Yes, with 1 query with 1 (while) loop will do the job.

Comment: Yes your answer worked.But you forgot  WHERE Follower='$Name'

Answer (score 1):

Try this, second loop should be put in the first loop.

```
<?php
    $query=$con->query("SELECT Following FROM followers WHERE Follower='$Name'");

    while ($row=$query->fetch_row()){
        $Follower=$row[0];
        $query2=$con->query("SELECT Image,`Text` FROM uploads WHERE Username='$Follower'");


        while ($row2=$query2->fetch_row()) {
            $Image=$row2[0];
            $Text=$row2[1];
            $Likes=$row2[2];
            $Comments=$row2[3];
            $Reposts=$row2[4];


            ?>
            <div class="PF">
                <img src="../users/<?php echo $roww[0] ?>" class="FollowerPic">
                <span><?php echo $Follower?></span>
            </div>

            <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: My respectful apologies for misunderstanding your code.

Comment: I guess it is my fault

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        $query=$con->query("SELECT Following FROM followers WHERE Follower='$Name'");

                while ($row=$query->fetch_row()){
                  $Follower=$row[0];
                  $query2=$con->query("SELECT Image,`Text` FROM uploads WHERE Username='$Follower'");

               while ($row2=$query2->fetch_row()) {
                 $Image=$row2[0];
                 $Text=$row2[1];
                 $Likes=$row2[2];
                 $Comments=$row2[3];
                 $Reposts=$row2[4];


  ?>
    <div class="PF">  
                  <img src="../users/<?php echo $Image ?>" class="FollowerPic">
                  <span><?php echo $Follower?></span>
                </div>

    <?php
                    }
   }
  ?>
```

Try this

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.